# C Programming : Confusion between operator precedence

Tags: c, operators, operator-precedence

I am confused between precedence of operators and want to know how this statement would be evaluated.

```
# include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int k=35;  
  printf("%d %d %d",k==35,k=50,k>40);  
  return 0;  
}
```

Here `k` is initially have value 35, when I am testing `k` in `printf` I think :

1. `k>40` should be checked  which should  result in 0
2. `k==35` should be checked and which should result in 1
3. Lastly  50  should get assigned to `k` and which should output 50

So final output should be `1 50 0`, but output is `0 50 1`.

Comment: That's an example of `undefined` behaviour

Comment: Operator precedence is irrelevant here.

Comment: on gcc version 4.4.3 it is `0 50 0` because it is UNDEFINED behaviour :(

Comment: Operator precedence controls how operators are grouped, but not the order in which they are executed - it controls *what* is evaluated, but not *when*.

Comment: @H2CO3 While the order of evaluation of function parameters is unspecified, I believe that this specific case is also undefined behavior, because `k` is accessed multiple times between seq. points for other purposes than to determine the value to be stored. C99 6.5/2: `Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression. Furthermore, the prior value shall be read only to determine the value to be stored.`

Comment: (the same applies in C11 6.5/2 but in C11 the above text has been replaced by gibberish meaning the same thing)

Comment: @Lundin 1. Calling a function with multiple arguments itself is not UB (that wouldn't be funny), it's just that the order of evaluation of the arguments is unspecified. I wasn't talking about the entire code itself, but the function arguments only. 2. This code, however, may invoke UB, but I still don't understand how your quote is relevant - as far as I know, there's a sequence point between the evaluation of function arguments, isn't there?

Comment: @H2CO3 The commas in the function call are just separators and do not introduce a sequence point. It will be several hours before I can update my answer with a quote though.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour So I was wrong regarding the sequence points. Thanks for the clarification! (The rest of my comment still stands, though.)

Comment: @H2CO3 "Calling a function with multiple arguments itself is not UB"  Umm, of course not, where did you get that idea from? Not from me. "it's just that the order of evaluation of the arguments is unspecified" That's what I said. "I wasn't talking about the entire code itself, but the function arguments only" So did I. "there's a sequence point between the evaluation of function arguments" No there is no sequence point there, function parameter lists is not the same thing as the comma operator. Since there is no sequence point, my quote is relevant at pointing out what makes this UB.

Comment: @Lundin Yes I was wrong about the sequence point, but please don't assume I am confusing function argument lists with the comma operator. **But:** the code wouldn't invoke UB if the `k = 50` expression wasn't there. That's what I was referring to.

Comment: I still don't get why people downvote these questions. If you don't know about sequence points and undefined behavior figuring this out is pretty hard.

Comment: Do you need any clarification on this question?

Answer (score 6):

You can not rely on the output of this program since it is [`undefined behavior`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), the evaluation order is not specified in C since that allows the compiler to optimize better, from the `C99` draft standard section `6.5` paragraph `3`:

> The grouping of operators and operands is indicated by the syntax.74) Except as specified
>   later (for the function-call (), &&, ||, ?:, and comma operators), **the order of evaluation of subexpressions and the order in which side effects take place are both unspecified.**

It is also undefined because you are accessing the value of `k` and assigning to it in the same [`sequence point`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point). From draft standard section `6.5` paragraph `2`:

> Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value
>   modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression. **Furthermore, the prior value
>   shall be read only to determine the value to be stored.**

it cites the following code examples as being undefined:

```
i = ++i + 1;
a[i++] = i;
```

**Update**

There was a comment as to whether the commas in the function call acted as a sequence point or not. If we look at section `6.5.17 Comma operator` paragraph `2` says:

> The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression; **there is a
>   sequence point after its evaluation.**

but paragraph `3` says:

> EXAMPLE As indicated by the syntax, the comma operator (as described in this subclause) **cannot appear in contexts where a comma is used to separate items in a list (such as arguments to functions or lists of initializers**).

So in this case the comma does not introduce a sequence point.

Answer (score 0):

The order in which function arguments are evaluated is not specified. They can be evaluated in any order. The compiler decides.

Answer (score 0):

This is [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You may get any value. Lack of [sequence points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) in two consecutive execution. Increase strictness level for warning and you will get `warning: operation on ‘k’ may be undefined`.